# Use different android switch style?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am very new to Android programming, but would like to change the style of my Switch View element so that it looks similar to the one that is displayed on the Android website: [image: Desired Switch Style]

and not like the one that I currently have:

[image: Current Switch Style]
[image: Current Switch Style 2]

I assume that because this is on the Android website it would not be difficult to change to this Switch style, but as I am new to Android development, I don't even have the faintest idea how to change this, and a large amount of time spent searching for the answer has not turned anything up as to what is causing my style to differ from the one on the website. Any help is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's actually different enough that its going to be a pain-  particularly the text on top of the switch instead of to the side.  But lets ignore that and assume you only want to get the rest of the look, that you don't want words  (words on a switch are a bad idea anyway, the word for "on" might be 7 characters in some language).

You can set the thumb drawable in xml via android:thumb.  You can set the drawable for the background with android:track.  If you want the side of the long area of the thumb to change,(its on top in your drawing on "on" and the bottom on "off") you'd need to change the thumb drawable when the state changes.  The tinting of the thumb/track are controlled by android:trackTint and android:thumbTint.

You can see the other switch-specific xml properties at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

Comment: Where do I find the different drawables? Is this baked into Android or would I need to download these from somewhere?

Comment: I also updated the picture with my *actual* switches, as I didn't want to cause confusion with the placement of the text, my text is on top of the switches as in the first example.

Comment: A drawable is an image.  You'd either find one online with an acceptable license, or draw it yourself.

Comment: ALso, while it allows you to put any string there, I really don't suggest it-  getting it to look good in every language is basically impossible.